# pointer to const object automatic cast to pointer to object

Tags: c++, pointers, casting, constants

Why is a const pointer automatically casted to a non-const pointer? In this simple code?
Shouldn't warn the compiler here? or throw an error?

```
template<typename T>
const T  makeConst(T a){
    return a;
}    

int * j = new int(9);
int * z = makeConst(j); // cast from int* const  ==>  int*
```

Comment: If you put the `const` after what it modifies, the problem should be obvious.  What is `T const`, if `T` is `int*`?

Comment: And of course, any top level `const` or `volatile` on a return value are ignored, unless the returned type is a class type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A (* const) pointer means the pointer's destination address cannot change, although the object at that address may be changed.

Your function returns a (* const) pointer, however the code compiles because the (* const) pointer is copied into your z variable, which does not change the actual pointer returned by makeConst, which then goes out of scope and is destroyed.

If you want to prevent modification to the target object through a pointer, place the const before the *.

Answer (score 2):

Its cuz an `int*const` is different that `const int*`. `int* const` means that you can't change what the pointer points to, but can change the value. This is how the compiler parses the `<typename T>` from a pointer. To get around this, we typically use templates like this:

```
template<typename T>
const T*  makeConst(T* a){
    return a;
}    

int * j = new int(9);
int * z = makeConst(j); // error C2440 in Visual Studio`
```